# Unable to open or edit resource file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am having some problem with my resource files. If I open it in VS2012, it doesn't show up. It just displays a stupid icon, and no error message or anything.

[image: Screenshot]

The same file, I can open in notepad, and it works fine, but VS is unable to read it at all. Sadly, because of this, all my labels are coming empty as well. I haven't changed anything in resource file, and yet somehow it stopped showing up.

Till now, I have tried deleting the file, adding it again, rebuilding the solution, unload and reload the project. Nothing works, and I am out of ideas to try. :/

Comment: I'm guessing that the file is malformed.  Since it's an xml file try opening it using a browser.  If there is a problem with the file, the browser will report it.

Comment: Browser doesn't report anything at all. It opens perfectly in older version of Visual Studio as well.

Comment: Should I post the full xml here? Also, I noted some keys with same name but different values. It didn't affected the older version, but it might be a problem. Although, I don't know how to find the duplicate keys faster than just going through the XML one key at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by **empty name attribute**.

I fixed it like this:

- Right click on resx file
- choose XML (Text) Editor
- check file content